# center images and add padding according to screen resolution

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame to show two images: I've maneged to resize the images according to the screen size of my user. But I'd like to standardized also the x and the y coordination position of my images. The images should always be in the middle according to the y axis and have the a little bit of pad to stay close to the border of the monitor like this no matter what resolution my user
has:

[image]

This are the values that I'd like to standardized

```
    WIN.blit(FIRST_IMG, (100, 280))

    WIN.blit(SECOND_IMAGE, (1350, 280))
```

This is my code right now:

```
import pygame
import os


WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

FPS = 60

SCREEN_INFO = pygame.display.Info()

IMAGE_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT = SCREEN_INFO.current_w // 5, SCREEN_INFO.current_h // 3

FIRST_IMG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "7.png"))
FIRST_IMG = pygame.transform.scale(FIRST_IMG, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))

SECOND_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "8.png"))
SECOND_IMAGE = pygame.transform.scale(SECOND_IMAGE, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))


def draw_window():
    WIN.fill(WHITE)

    WIN.blit(FIRST_IMG, (100, 280))

    WIN.blit(SECOND_IMAGE, (1350, 280))

    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False

        draw_window()

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the bounding rectangle of the image and set the `centery` and `left` or right of the rectangle depending on the size of `WIN`. Use the rectangles to `blit` the images:

```py
def draw_window():
    width, height = WIN.get_size()

    WIN.fill(WHITE)

    first_rect = FIRST_IMG.get_rect(midleft = (100, height // 2))
    WIN.blit(FIRST_IMG, first_rect)

    second_rect = FIRST_IMG.get_rect(midright = (width - 100, height // 2))
    WIN.blit(SECOND_IMAGE, second_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```